# Error : Insert Cells into a Section

Tags: objective-c, button, insert, row, uitableview

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update'

```
-(void)actionAddMore:(UIButton *)sender{

[_tblTask beginUpdates];
[_tblTask insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[_tblTask endUpdates];

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvHVY.png)

Comment: Did you insert data into the actual datasource?

Comment: Thanks you very much ! Yes.I used to CollectionView.When clicked will addobject into nsmutablearray
-(void)bidirectionalCollectionView:(JCBidirectionalCollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString* sectionMonday = @"Monday";

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 1:
            
            [self dictionaryOfDayAddToTableView:_dictionoryOfDay arrayOfDay:_arrOfMonday key:sectionMonday];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    [_tblTask reloadData];
}

Comment: -(void)dictionaryOfDayAddToTableView:(NSMutableDictionary *)dict arrayOfDay:(NSMutableArray *)array key:(NSString *)key{
    [array addObject:key];
    [dict setObject:array
                         forKey:key];
}

Comment: I am sorry . I'm not so good at English. :)

Comment: Please add your code **well formatted** to your question.

Comment: Thanks !.It' s already done

Comment: No, I meant the extra code from the comments. It's really hard to read it down here ;)